# Dictionary Object

Tags: asp.net

Can you iterate through a dictionary object that can contain a object and enum types

```
foreach(Dictionary<someObject, enumType> myDic in myObjects) {
    if(enumType.myType == enumType.Type) {
        do something here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear; can you explain some background about what you are trying to do, and if you are dealing with a single `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, a collection of dictionaries, etc.?

Comment: I was thinking to solve my question about the pager that I might store the link object and have that object as a type of enum to determine if that link was the current page so I could create an empty link like a div with that number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, enumType> foo in myObjects)
{
      if(foo.Value == enumType.Type)
      {
            // do your thang
      }

}
```